# Unable to use <% ... %> in a client side button click event

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, inline-code

I am trying to redirect to a different page based upon a value in the querystring. This is an asp.net web form page. When the cancel button is clicked the following js should execute. The button is an devexpress button.

```
function OnCancelClick(s, e) {
    if (confirm('If you leave this page, you have to reselect the benefits. Are you sure to leave this page?')) {
        var callingPage = document.getElementById("<%= CallingPage.ClientID %>").value;
        alert("Calling Page: " + callingPage);
        if (callingPage == "AddEmployee.aspx") {
            window.location.href = ResolveUrl('~/Member/Maintenance/AddEmployee.aspx?from=VerifyPage');
        } else if (callingPage == "AddDependentMember.aspx") {

        }
    }
```

CallingPage is the ID of an asp hidden field. I am setting its value during the page load. Even before this page is loaded I am getting The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. `<% ... %>`)
error. Not sure whether it is due to devexpress button control or something else.

Comment: 1. You have a syntax error - missing a `}` at the end. 2. Are you within the context of the asp.net page? This code would not execute in a .js file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this is an unique issue related to devexpress controls. It looks like that we can't use <% %> within the js clientside click event of a devexpress button click event. Instead I used devexpress's hidden control, then it worked fine.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assign the CallingPage.ClientID to a server side page variable with public accessibility:

```
public partial class <class / page name> : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string callingPage = "";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.callingPage = CallingPage.ClientID;

        ...
    }
}
```

then in your javascript:

```
var callingPage = document.getElementById("<%= this.callingPage %>").value;
```